# How to set local JSON data as state using hooks React

Tags: json, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am new to React and trying to get the hang of hooks in function components.
I have a Products array of objects in a local .json file in the public dir of my app. In my src dir I have my Products component. I need to bring the .json data into this component and render it on the page.
I use the useState() hook to set products and and the setProducts const's. Then I fetch the json data using the getData function, which calls setProducts using that data (I think). getData() gets caled in the useEffect hook. Then I render that to the page using a .map function.

I added a statement to check that the data was fetched, however now nothing is rendering in the browser and console.log(products) gets me an empty array, so I know the data isn't being set correctly.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Products() {

    const [products, setProducts]=useState([]);
    const getData=()=>{
      fetch('data.json'
      ,
      {
        headers : { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
         }
      }
      )
        .then(function(response){
          console.log(response)
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(myJson) {
           console.log(myJson);
          setProducts(myJson)
        });
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
      getData()
    },[])

    return (
        <div>
            <ul className="products">
                {products.length > 0 && products.map(product => (
                    <li key={product._id}>
                        <div className="product">
                            <a href={"#" + product._id}>
                                <img src={product.image} alt={product.title} />
                                <p>
                                    {product.title}
                                </p>
                            </a>
                            <div className="productPrice">
                                <div>
                                    {product.price}
                                </div>
                                <button className="button primary">
                                    Add to cart
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for products to be fetched by doing something like this

```
<ul className="products">
  { products.length > 0 && products.map(product => (
     <li key={product._id}>
     // ...
  }
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok that does remove the error, howver it's still not rendering the data on the page. When I add anything to inside the map function, like "hello", it's not rendering that either.

Comment: And the console.log(products) returns an empty array

Answer (score 0):

Check if the response is not empty, everything other in the code is correct.

EDIT

Then setProducts(myJson.body). Becouse now yuo are setting products to the whole response object instead of the body of the response.
Or set what you need from the body if it is not array of products

Comment: this is what the response looks like:  
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/data.json", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3000/data.json"
__proto__: Response